# Assigning select results into variable in stored procedure in mssql?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following select:

```
SELECT School_Type,COUNT(ID) from Schools where City_ID = 1 group by School_Type
```

I get results:

```
10 | 3
20 | 4
30 | 14
```

I want to put results that are:

- type 10 to variable `@ElementarySchools`
- type 20 to variable `@HighSchools`
- type 30 to variable `@ProfessionalSchools`

and get this result back from the Stored Procedure.

How do I do this ?

Comment: if you want to return those values from stored proc, why do you assign it to a variable? are these output variables of the SP?

Answer (score 0):

something like this? :)

```
declare @val varchar(max) = ''
select @val = @val + rtrim(foryear) + ' | ' + RTRIM( COUNT(*)) + ',' from mytable
group by ForYear

select @val
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a table variable like this:

```
declare @tmp table (School_Type int, School_Count int)
insert into @tmp
SELECT School_Type,COUNT(ID) from Schools where City_ID = 1 group by School_Type

select @ElementarySchools=School_Count from @tmp where School_Type=10
select @HighSchools=School_Count from @tmp where School_Type=20
select @ProfessionalSchools=School_Count from @tmp where School_Type=30
```